# If $f$ is integrable, the sequence $f(x+n) \to 0$ for $n \in \mathbb{R}$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to prove the following statement:

If $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $m$, the sequence $f(x+n) \to 0$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ as $n \to \infty$ for almost every $x \in [0,1]$

I know somewhere I have to use the fact that the Lebesgue integral is translation invariant, which I have proven. Now, my problem is to find something I can work with, but I am very lost.

Comment: You are referring to a 'sequence' but you want to let $n \to infty$ through real numbers. Clarify whether $n$ is an integer variable or  a real variable.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2045509/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1532581/42969.